# AMPScript does not look to be working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a column called First Name in Data Extension `TriggeredSendDataExtension - 20160917_111231`. I am trying to print FromEmail from the data extension row by passing the first name as the send time parameter. But it does not looks to be working. I am keeping this in Email Template.

```
Set @FromEmail = Lookup("TriggeredSendDataExtension - 20160917_111231", "FromEmail", "First Name", %%First Name%%)

%%=v(@FromEmail )=%%

Here 
dataExtension - TriggeredSendDataExtension - 20160917_111231
returnColumn - FromEmail
matchColumn - First Name
value - %%First Name%%
```

Also I have tried the below pattern. It is also does not seem to be working.

```
  %%[ 
 SET @MYSUB= %%Subject%%
 Set @Subject= Lookup("TriggeredSendDataExtension - 20160917_111231", "FromEmail", "Subject", @MYSUB) ]%%

    %%=v(@Subject)=%%
```

With this I am getting

```
Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
Script Expression: %%Subject%%
MemberID: 7273985
JobID: 0
```

How do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass %%First Name%% directly in any LookUp function.

I would suggest you to use [AttributeValue AmpSCript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/attributevalue/#attributevalue) function and initialize `First Name` in variable.

```
%%[
SET @FirstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
SET @FromEmail = Lookup("TriggeredSendDataExtension - 20160917_111231", "FromEmail", "First Name", @FirstName)
]%%

%%=v(@FromEmail)=%%
```